# Why does the string returned as "4-5 u043Bu0435u0442 103-112 u0441u043C"?

Tags: java, json, spring, character-encoding

I am developing backend which collect data from different sources (REST APIs) and return summarized data.

So I requesting data from one of APIs. Response from that API is (all Cyrillic characters looks good) described as `@Data class ProductSku {private string label; private boolean isInStock;}`:

```json
[
   {
      //... omit lot of unused fields
      "label": "1 год 73-75 см",
      "isInStock": true
   },
   {
      //... omit lot of unused fields
      "label": "2 года 82-88 см",
      "isInStock": true
   }
]
```

Then I allow to request it among other datas from my backend endpoint:

```java
@GetMapping(path = "products/{prodId}", produces = {"application/json; charset=UTF-8","*/*;charset=UTF-8"})
    public ProductEntity getProduct(@PathVariable("prodId") int prodId) {
        return catalogService.getProduct(prodId);
    }
```

```java
class CatalogService {
    public ProductEntity getProduct(int prodId) {
        // ...
        // ommited fill up result from other APIs 

        List<ProductData> productSkus = stockClient.getProductSkus(prodId);
        productEntity.addSkus(productSkus);

        return productEntity;
    }
}
```

```java
class StockClient {

    public List<ProductSku> getProductSkus(int prodId) {
        // using restTemplate
        // querying by param productId

        ProductData[] productsData;
        try {
            var headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            headers.set(HttpHeaders.PRAGMA, "no-cache");
            headers.set(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, "no-cache");

            var uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(apiUrl).queryParam("productId", prodId).build().toUri();
            var requestEntity = RequestEntity.get(uri).headers(headers).build();
            productsData = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, ProductData[].class).getBody();

        } catch (...) { 
           //... 
        }

       // convert to list here
       return new Arrays.asList(productData);
    }
}
// ...
```

So it respond me as:

```json
{
   // ...
   "skus": [
        {
            "size": "1 u0433u043Eu0434 73-75 u0441u043C",
            "inStock": true
        },
        {
            "size": "2 u0433u043Eu0434u0430 82-88 u0441u043C",
            "inStock": true
        }
    ]
    // ...
}
```

As you can see instead of `"2 года 82-88 см"` i get `"2 u0433u043Eu0434u0430 82-88 u0441u043C"`

Cyrillic symbols from other APIs appears normally.

I am hope for your help

Comment: Did it get backslashes before `uXXXX`s lost?

Comment: I see several problems (but I do not know well Java nor Spring): someone the data il converted to `2 \u0433(...)` which it is correct Unicode (but not yet encoded to UTF-8. This string is wrongly converted (I assume) with `\` instead of an escape sequence. And some parts will eliminate problematic characters. Which is very wrong and unsafe (substitute, never remove, or there is high security risk of abusing such methods to skip other checks).

Comment: @fluffy from source API it come as cyrillic symbols "2 года 82-88 см", and after i returned this string from my backend It is shown as above - as unicode code points with no any backslash.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi its strange because i did not doing any conversion by self. May be something under the hood of Jackson happens so such behavior is occur.

Comment: @Валерий it's sort strange (as of now) and I guess you have to debug: first make sure your `productsData` do not lose Cyrillic characters by simply logging their to-strings. If it's fine, second, make sure your controller does not do any wrong transformations for the response entity (it's hard to believe that the HTTP message converter does that, so probably some filter does).

Comment: @fluffy 
I followed your recommendation and set RestTemplate Interceptor to log response from source API, and also added logging of final entity i returned from my backend to check result after Jackson have his conversion done. Will wait for logging results.